# Transform part of string in Python

Tags: python, string

Let us say I have the following string:

```
MARKDOWN: [This link](http://example.net/)
```

Which I want to transform to

```
MARKDOWN: [link=http://example.net]This link[/link]
```

What is the best approach for this and how do I do it, note there can be multiple links in one line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can have a regex to match the first markdown, capture the desired group and append it to `[link=...]...[/link]`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun mind showing some code? I am still new at python

Comment: I won't be really helping you if I do.. I suggest you try something by yourself first, and we're here in case you'll have troubles.

Comment: You can achieve this using regular expression module in python,take a look at these pages for a start https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html?highlight=howto and https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this through [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) function,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "MARKDOWN: [This link](http://example.net/)"
>>> m = re.sub(r'\[([^]]*)\]\((.*?)\/\)', r'[link=\2]\1[/link]', s)
>>> m
'MARKDOWN: [link=http://example.net]This link[/link]'
```

Exclude `/)` from capturing by the second group. So that you won't get last `/` in the link value.(ie, `http://example.net`). And also you could make the last `\/` as optional because some links may or maynot contains `/` at the last. Hence the regex would be,

```
>>> m = re.sub(r'\[([^]]*)\]\((.*?)\/?\)', r'[link=\2]\1[/link]', s)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sJ4jD7/1)

Comment: Dose not work, I get this using 2: sre_constants.error: invalid group reference

Comment: post your `re.sub` line.

Comment: lines[x] = re.sub(r'\[([^]]*)\]\((.*?)\/?\)', r'[link=\2]\1[/link]', lines[x])

Comment: FOUND the mistake my bad sorry I had a tab to much - THANKS

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub(r"\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\/?\)", r"[link=\2]\1[/link]",
    "MARKDOWN: [This link](http://example.net/) and this [this](www.google.com)")

# output:
'MARKDOWN: [link=http://example.net]This link[/link] and
this [link=www.google.com]this[/link]'
```

Comment: @Netfas would you mind checking my edit and se how I can This link otherwise your answer works flawlessly :) so thanks

Comment: @LarsNielsen done. You should really check out the [Python regex tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/regex.html), it's great :)

Comment: i'm not the downvoter but it may bacause of op / in the link. That is, op wants `[link=http://example.net]` not `[link=http://example.net/]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj that's easy to overcome :)